# Multiplying 2 pandas dataframes generates nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes as below

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'val1' : [1,2,1,2,4], 'val2' : [1,2,1,2,4]})
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'val3' : [1,2,1,2,4]})
```

Now with each column of `dat` and want to multiply `dat1`. So I did below

```
dat * dat1
```

However this generates `nan` value for all elements.

Could you please help on what is the correct approach? I could run a `for` loop with each column of dat, but I wonder if there are any better method available to perform the same.

Thanks for your pointer.

Comment: You need `axis=0` because default axis is `1`: Check `dat.mul(data1, axis=0)`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma as `dat1` too is a frame it won't help

Comment: @MustafaAydın Correct! Its typo.. it should be `dat.mul(data1['val3'], axis=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing multiplication (or any arithmetic operation), pandas does index alignment. This goes for both the index *and* columns in case of dataframes. If matches, it multiplies; otherwise puts NaN and the result has the union of the indices and columns of the operands.

So, to "avoid" this alignment, make `dat1` a label-unaware data structure, e.g., a NumPy array:

```py
In [116]: dat * dat1.to_numpy()
Out[116]:
   val1  val2
0     1     1
1     4     4
2     1     1
3     4     4
4    16    16
```

---

To see what's "really" being multiplied, you can `align` yourself:

```py
In [117]: dat.align(dat1)
Out[117]:
(   val1  val2  val3
 0     1     1   NaN
 1     2     2   NaN
 2     1     1   NaN
 3     2     2   NaN
 4     4     4   NaN,
    val1  val2  val3
 0   NaN   NaN     1
 1   NaN   NaN     2
 2   NaN   NaN     1
 3   NaN   NaN     2
 4   NaN   NaN     4)
```

(extra: you have the indices same for `dat` & `dat1`; please change one of them's index, and then `align` again to see the union-behaviour.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two things:

- use [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with `axis=0`
- use a Series instead of dat1 (else multiplication will try to align the indices, there is no common ones between your two dataframes

```
out = dat.mul(dat1['val3'], axis=0)
```

output:

```
   val1  val2
0     1     1
1     4     4
2     1     1
3     4     4
4    16    16
```